# Conditional Difference of Two Rows based on Two Different Groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Following data set contains hourly accumulated rainfall. I want to calculate hourly rainfall rate by calculating difference of rainfall in two consecutive hour.

**The problem is rainfall measurement starts everyday at 09:00 hr. So I want to start finding difference between two consecutive rows of `hr_rain` column from 09 hour of say 06/02/18 to 08 hour of 06/03/18 and again same for next day**.

I cannot simply start with 09 hr and go for next 24 records as for some days some observations for `hr_rain` are missing.
The sample data is as follows:

```
 STATION    CODE  DATE     HOUR hr_rain
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    00  1.0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    04  1.0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    05  1.0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    06  1.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    07  2.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    08  2.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    09  0.0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    10  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    11  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    12  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    13  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    14  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    15  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    16  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    17  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    18  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    19  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    03  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    05  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    06  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    07  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    08  0.5
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    09  0.0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    10  0.0
```

I tried with

```
df %>%  group_by(DATE) %>% mutate( RAINFALL = hr_rain - lag(hr_rain, default = 0))
```

but it does grouping according to `DATE` and give results from 0 hr of a day to 23 hr of a day and starts over again for next day. But I want to start at 09 hr of everyday till 8 o hr of next day.
What I want is :

```
STATION    CODE  DATE     HOUR hr_rain rainfall

SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    00  1.0    1
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    04  1.0    0 
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    05  1.0    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    06  1.5    0.5 
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    07  2.5    1 
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    08  2.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    09  0.0    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    10  0.5    0.5 
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    11  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    12  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    13  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    14  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    15  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    16  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    17  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    18  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/09/18    19  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    03  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    05  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    06  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    07  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    08  0.5    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    09  0.0    0
SHIVAMOGGA  163 06/10/18    10  0.0    0
```

As a beginner in R, I might indeed be missing something simple. I would appreciate any insights how to do this in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create groups when `HOUR == 9`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(HOUR == 9)) %>%
  #Maybe you'll also need to add more groups
  #group_by(STATION, CODE, gr = cumsum(HOUR == 9)) %>%
  mutate(RAINFALL = hr_rain - lag(hr_rain, default = 0))

#  STATION     CODE DATE      HOUR hr_rain RAINFALL
#   <fct>      <int> <fct>    <int>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18     0     1        1  
# 2 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18     4     1        0  
# 3 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18     5     1        0  
# 4 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18     6     1.5      0.5
# 5 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18     7     2.5      1  
# 6 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18     8     2.5      0  
# 7 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18     9     0        0  
# 8 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18    10     0.5      0.5
# 9 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18    11     0.5      0  
#10 SHIVAMOGGA   163 06/09/18    12     0.5      0  
# … with 14 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(STATION = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "SHIVAMOGGA", class = "factor"), CODE = c(163L, 
163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 
163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 
163L), DATE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("06/09/18", 
"06/10/18"), class = "factor"), HOUR = c(0L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 3L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), hr_rain = c(1, 1, 1, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: I grouped by HOUR ==9 but for 9 HOUR its giving result of 9 hr_rainfall - 8 hr_rainfall (i.e. instead of 0 its giving -2.5 here)

Comment: @Ajay Is your actual dataframe different than your data shared here because I think using the data shared here it gives the expected output. Does it gives the same to you?

Comment: My dataframe is having two more columns of DISTRICT and TALUK. As I told in earlier comment I'm getting difference of 9 hr_rainfall and 8 hr_rainfall for 9 HOUR. (i.e. -2.5).

Comment: @Ajay ok, that is probably because you have `plyr` loaded in your environment which is masking `mutate`, Try `df %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(HOUR == 9)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(RAINFALL = hr_rain - lag(hr_rain, default = 0))`

Comment: Still the output is same.

Comment: I hope you are assigning the output back. `df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(gr = cumsum(HOUR == 9))....` . If it is still not working please add your data as `dput` as I have added at the end of my post so that it is easier to debug. As of now, I am not able to reproduce what you get as you can see I get expected output as shown in my answer.

Comment: I think you could not paste the `dput` correctly. 
It is better to add it to your post. Do you have `HOUR` column as integer or character? If it is character you can try to change `group_by` statement to `group_by(gr = cumsum(HOUR == '09'))`

Comment: HOUR column is character. I tried your last suggestion and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I first did grouping to fill NA values in data set ```df1 <- df %>% group_by(STATION, CODE, gr = cumsum(HOUR == '09')) %>% mutate(hr_rain := na.approx(hr_Rain, rule = 2,  maxgap = 2, na.rm = FALSE))``` and again I tried grouping to get hourly value starting from 9 ```hourly_df <- df1 %>%  group_by(STATION, CODE , grp = cumsum(HOUR == '09')) %>% mutate(RAINFALL = hr_rain - lag(hr_rain, default = 0))``` but it's creating desire groups. It starts creates first group properly but second group continues till end of dataframe.

Comment: @Ajay Don't use `:=` in `mutate`. Can you post a new question with additional details?